# Libcgroups Compilation Error

Tags: c, cgroups

When trying to start cgroups within a small c group I get the following error

```
 In file included from /usr/include/libcgroup.h:24:0,
                 from simple_cgroup.h:28,
                  from simple_cgroup.cc:1: /usr/include/libcgroup/groups.h:108:8: error: forward declaration of
 ‘struct cgroup’  struct cgroup;
```

The code that uses these headers is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sched.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <libcgroup.h>
```

I compile using g++ with the -lcgroup flag..

Help is much appreciated as to why this is happening